# How do I get the request id from RequestIDLogFilter in python flask?

Tags: python, flask, python-logging

So, in my main `app.py`, I have :

```
app = create_app()

...
app.run()
```

In `__init__.py` I have:

```
def create_app():
  ...
  app = Flask(__name__)
  setup_logging(app)
  return app

def setup_logging(app):
  RequestID(app)
  handler = logging.FileHandler(app.container.config.get("app.LOG_FILE"))
  handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s : %(levelname)s : %(request_id)s - %(message)s"))
  handler.addFilter(RequestIDLogFilter())  # << Add request id contextual filter
  logging.getLogger().addHandler(handler)
  logging.getLogger().setLevel(level="DEBUG")
```

And in my `routes.py`, I have: (This wiring/linking is done with the help of dependency injection)

```
def configure(app):
    app.add_url_rule("/", "check", check)
    ...

def check():
    logging.info("You hit /")
     # Here I want to return the Request UUID that's generated by RequestLogIDFilter
    return make_response(jsonify(dict(ok=True)), 200)
```

How do I access the Request UUID generated by the `RequestLogIDFilter`? In my log file I correctly see the log messages as:

```
2022-08-15 07:00:18,030 : INFO : 27b437fd-98be-4bc9-a609-912043e3a38e - Log message test memberId=9876
```

I want to take this value `27b437fd-98be-4bc9-a609-912043e3a38e` and include it in the response headers as `X-REQUEST-UUID: 27b437fd-98be-4bc9-a609-912043e3a38e`

---

An alternative was to rip out `RequestLogIDFilter` and only work with `flask-request-id-header` except, there's no way to write it to log file (`logging.FileHandler` does not have a `write()` method so it fails)

---

This is something trivial I'm sure but the official docs nowhere mention how to access these request ids for logging to file or sending back as a response header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `flask_log_request_id` then you probably want this as [given in their github repo](https://github.com/Workable/flask-log-request-id#example-4-if-you-want-to-return-request-id-in-response)

Code copied here in case link does not work

```
from flask_log_request_id import current_request_id

@app.after_request
def append_request_id(response):
    response.headers.add('X-REQUEST-ID', current_request_id())
    return response
```